# PHP : JasperReports graph is not displaying in html although it is displaying in pdf

Tags: php, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

The below code are working currectly

```
$jasper = new RequestJasper();

header('Content-type: application/pdf'); 

echo $jasper->run('/reports/samples/StandardChartsReport','pdf');
```

In pdf data and graphs both are displaying currect

But when I want to get the result in html then it shows the output in binary format.

**code**

```
$jasper = new RequestJasper();

header('Content-type: text/html');

echo $jasper->run('/reports/samples/StandardChartsReport','html');
```

**output**

```
-Type: image/png Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary Content-Id: ‰PNG  IHDR+,Có +ÁIDATxÚíå½î»(ŠÊ–u-NÊ¢Ræz9Ö¹–EíÕkYE   "á‘]vW`q%ü"*‰^D‹PNˆ‰H8£—2„`ŽÆ¬`¸\4•(I¸[d= ”Ä áp–u\xïûî¾S4MwÏÛ³Ý½oÏ|>Ô·fº™žyçí·ß~æéggjPÞÿKëõzd”ÕRÁöI<Þû~U;f÷ã=]!ëY]²:d]ŸP®bx¤+LÊ½Ž:©Ÿ ÷å]?RJY/k¢¾?KÖÞ„úU0,¢OŒ~— .....
```

How can get this result in html so that i can put it inside a div?

**$jaisper object value**

```
Report\Jasper\Adl\Integration\RequestJasper Object

(
    [jasperServer:Report\Jasper\Adl\Integration\RequestJasper:private] => Report\Jasper\Adl\Config\JasperServer Object

    (
        [wsdl:Report\Jasper\Adl\Config\JasperServer:private] => http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/services/repository?wsdl

        [username:Report\Jasper\Adl\Config\JasperServer:private] => joeuser

        [password:Report\Jasper\Adl\Config\JasperServer:private] => joeuser

        [pathToSave:Report\Jasper\Adl\Config\JasperServer:private] => /Users/adlermedrado/tmp
    )
)
```